# Cypress Error: Failed to parse or set cookie named

Tags: cypress

Upgraded from Cypress version 3.1.0 to 3.3.1 and started seeing the following error every time a test is run.

> cy.visit() failed trying to load
>
> We received this error at the network level:
>
> Error: Failed to parse or set cookie named "cookie-name".

The stack trace is as follows:

Chrome 75:

> undefined

Electron 61:

> Error: Setting cookie failed

Does anyone know what changed from version 3.1.0 onwards that could be causing this issue and is there a workaround besides reverting?

`Edit: Zach correctly deduced the problem stemming from the server trying to set a secure cookie on a site that is not secure. This presents a problem since the server cannot be changed and securing the domain in question is not really an option. Aside from being perpetually stuck on version 3.1.0 any ideas for workarounds or reverting the change would be appreciated.`

Comment: Can you share the code that sets the cookie?

Comment: The cookie is set by the server so there is no code to share in this regard.

Comment: Yes, that code. :) I've only seen this error when you try to set a `secure` cookie on a non-HTTPS origin, could that be it?

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood. You are correct in that the cookie is secure and the domain is not. "Set-Cookie: key=value; path=/; secure; HttpOnly". Thanks for providing an avenue to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is already an open issue for this in Github. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3525

In version 3.1.1 they fixed some issues regarding secure cookie expiration and this appears to be a side effect.